# Replacing multiple characters of a string using multiple ternary operators

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-operator

I am trying to solve a simple problem in JavaScript. I have to take a string of characters and do the following substitutions:

```
G -> C
C -> G
T -> A
A -> U
```

So for example if the input is `ATCG` the output would be `UAGC`

Initially I thought to convert the string to an array and then use `map()` on it. But why to iterate over the string twice when the job could be done in a single iteration?

So I looked for other ways, like RegExp, but it seems that the only way to do multiple substitutions is to chaining multiple `replace()` and this would indeed be even more inefficient.

So I thought to use a `for...of` and I wrote this code:

```js
let s = 'ATGC*';

let r = '';

for(const x of s) r += x === 'C' ? 'G' : 'G' ? 'C' : 'T' ? 'A' : 'A' ? 'U' : '-NaN-';

console.log(r);
```

It seems to convert `C` to `G` and everything else to `C`.

I think it should work like this:

```
x ===    // if the current character is equal to
'C' ?    // `C` 
'G' :    // r += `G`
'G' ?    // else if it is equal to `G`
'C' :    // r += `C`
'T' ?    // else if it is equal to `T`
'A' :    // r += `A`
'A' ?    // else if it is equal to `A`
'U' :    // r += `U`
'-NaN-'; // else it is not a nucleotide
```

Anyone with an idea of what is actually going on?

Comment: Don't use a ternary.... just a look up object....

Comment: The part before the question mark is evaluated for truthiness. So in your code, `x === 'C'` is evaluated, then, if false, `'G'` is evaluated. Strings with a value are considered truthy, so 'C' is the final stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really like to take ternaries, you could take this approach with multiple conditions.

```
r += x === 'G'
    ? 'C'
    : x === 'C'
        ? 'G'
        : x === 'T'
            ? 'A'
            : 'U'
```

A better approach is to take an object for replacing the values.

```
nucleobases = { G: 'C', C: 'G', T: 'A', A: 'U' }
```

Later take replacements with

```
r += nucleobases[x];
```

Comment: Oh you are right, I should have used `x ===` multiple times. Thanks also for the object suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a ternary, but does not make much sense, but it can be done. You need to do the check for each letter.

```js
let s = 'ATGC*';

let r = '';

for (const x of s) r += 
  x === "G" ? "C" : 
    x === "C" ? "G" : 
     x === "T" ? "A" :
       x === "A" ? "U" : x;

console.log(r);
```

Ternary is way too complicated for this. Just use a simple object look up.

```js
var replacements = {
  G: 'C',
  C: 'G',
  T: 'A',
  A: 'U',
}

let s = 'ATGC*';

let r = '';

for (const x of s) r += replacements[x] || x;

console.log(r);
```

And how I would code it

```js
const replacements = {
  G: 'C',
  C: 'G',
  T: 'A',
  A: 'U',
}

const s = 'ATGC*';

const re = new RegExp(`[${Object.keys(replacements).join('')}]`,'g');

const r = s.replace(re, x => replacements[x]);
console.log(r);
```